# using $(this) in a custom plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, this

I have a plugin that adds a pseudo event handler. The user will then pass a function in the parameter, much like you would in any assigned event in jQuery. How would one add the `$(this)` functionality in the function that the user can use in the custom function? Also, please let me know the proper terminology if there is any.

```
// Implementation
$("some_selector").myCustomHandler(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});

// Plugin

(function( $ ){

   $.fn.myCustomHandler = function(fn){
   //some code
   //some code
   // then do this:
       fn();
   }
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might be looking for

```
(function( $ ){

   $.fn.myCustomHandler = function(fn){
   //some code
   //some code
   // then do this:
       this.each(function(idx, el){
           fn.call(this, idx, el)
       })
   }
})( jQuery );
```

or even

```
(function( $ ){

   $.fn.myCustomHandler = function(fn){
   //some code
   //some code
   // then do this:
       this.each(fn)
   }
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Any chance You could reword my question using proper terminology? I would love to know if I should use other terms to refer to `$(this)` and `this` and so on. Thank you.